# Sending a mail to any message server (Gmail, Yahoo etc) without password authentication in Java

Tags: java, email, servlets

We are developing a simple web application in *JSF* in which there is a need to include a "forget password" module. For the sake of demonstration and simplicity, I tried the following code in Java Servlet. It can send a mail to Gmail and works just fine there is no problem at all. The following is the complete Servlet code.

```
public class MailClient extends HttpServlet {

    private class SMTPAuthenticator extends Authenticator {

        private PasswordAuthentication authentication;

        public SMTPAuthenticator(String login, String password) {
            authentication = new PasswordAuthentication(login, password);
        }

        @Override
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return authentication;
        }
    }

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request,
         HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        try {
            String from = "bhaveshp1980@gmail.com";
            String to = "bhaveshp1980@gmail.com";
            String subject = "A mail from Java.";
            String message = "My first mail from Java.";
            String login = "bhaveshp1980@gmail.com";
            String password = "password";

            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.setProperty("mail.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
            props.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "587");
            props.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
            props.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");

            Authenticator auth = new SMTPAuthenticator(login, password);
            Session session = Session.getInstance(props, auth);
            MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);

            try {
                msg.setText(message);
                msg.setSubject(subject);
                msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
                msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                        new InternetAddress(to));
                Transport.send(msg);
            } catch (MessagingException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(MailClient.class.getName()).
                        log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        } finally {
            out.close();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }
}
```

---

Now, the **first** question is that as soon as a user enters his valid email address, a verification code should be submitted to a specific message server (Gmail, Yahoo and so on) *without asking the user for his password (Which is not the case of the above code)* which is essential in implementing the "forget password" module in a web application.

The **second** question is that the above code is bound to sending a mail only to Gmail. If I want to send a mail to some other message server say Yahoo, the statement

```
props.setProperty("mail.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
```

needs to be changed to

```
props.setProperty("mail.host", "smtp.mail.yahoo.com");
```

[and port no too, regarding others] means that a specific message server to which a message has to be sent need to be recognized properly. Which is the best way to do so?. What is the best method(s) to overcome these issues, please.

Comment: Why do you need to switch your outgoing mail server depending on the email address? Typically you use an internal smtp server to send mail out.

Comment: Your assumptions are wrong.  You can send an email to anyone via a single SMTP server.  The account you use to send email FROM has nothing to do with who you are sending email TO.  In your case, you will likely have an email server from your hosting provider that you send mail from (and possibly authenticate to) but you should be able to send to any recipient; you don't need to use the mail server of the target domain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you change your SMTP settings in your email client each time you send a mail to a different mail provider? No. You don't set the SMTP server to gmail when sending a mail to a gmail.com address. And then set it to yahoo when sending a mail to a yahoo.com address. You set it to **your** email provider SMTP server, and this SMTP server sends the mail to the appropriate location.

Just choose an SMTP server which agrees to send mails from your application. Sending a dozen per day will be OK with any SMTP provider. But if you send thousands a day, then you could have problems with your provider. Just ask your hosting provider how it goes with outgoing mails (how much it costs, how many per day are accepted, is there a bandwidth limit, etc.)

Answer (score -1):

1. You need to generate a random token and send it as part of the
   message. You store the token in the database with an association to
   the user's profile. When the user returns to your site with that
   token (by entering it into a form, or by clicking a link with that
   token as GET parameter) you can be sure the user is authentic and
   offer the reset password dialog.
2. Don't send the message to the smtp server of the recipient, but to
   the smtp server of your from email address. So sending it to gmail
   would be fine. I would make stmp host url, username and password
   configurable, e.g. in a property file.

Answer (score -1):

So you can't do that.  That's the whole point of keeping people from spamming, masquerading as users they aren't, and lots of other nasty things.

You need to setup a SMTP server or get your domain hosted on a mail service that you can send mail through.  Maybe your ISP or hosting provider provides this already and you just need to sign up for that.  Otherwise, there are plenty of places out there that will allow you to send mail from your domain.  I use:

http://www.authsmtp.com/

Or you can have google host your domain for free, but they put a limit on the number of messages you can send per day which last time I checked was like 100.  So if your site plans on sending more mail than that you need to bump up to paid service like authsmtp.

http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/business/smb/email.html#utm_campaign=en&utm_source=en-ha-na-us-sk&utm_medium=ha&utm_term=%2Bemail%20%2Bhosting

Basically you need to find a mail server that is in charge of your MX record so emails sent to your domain will get routed to those servers, and so you application can send email from your domain and not get black listed as a spammer because you are doing naughty things.

While you can setup your own smtp server it's just so much easier to use a service, and that gives you a professional look for doing things like customer service, and responding to people when you mail comes from a domain associated with your website and not some johnnyappleseed@gmail.com

You need to do some basic research about how email works from a technical perspective as well.  That will help you understand why what I'm talking about is important.

Answer (score -1):

The authentication part you cannot get around. This is configured in the remote server, so unless you use your own mailserver, you have to do what gmail asks you to do. But instead of hardcoding the login/password, you could store them in an (encrypted?) properties file and modify that whenever you want to use another mailserver.